# Is it possible to protect our documents from getting copied using HTML 5 or general Web technologies?

Tags: html, pdf, ms-office

I want to develop a Web App for Mobile users, which will provide users with documents for users to view. I want to ensure that the documents once downloaded to temp folder needs to be deleted once user closes the window. Is there any option for this in HTML 5?

Is there any provision to disable copy/paste options for when browser shows the specific pdf documents or MS office documents?

**UPDATE1:**
Two things I need to know if possible:

1. Ability to delete files through an API
2. Disable copy, paste option through Browser for Documents. (might seem like a fantasy)

Comment: How does the browser display the documents? Are they downloaded? Or do you have a built-in viewer?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Yes they are downloaded. But is it possible to develop a separate viewer that will ensure the file dont really gets downloaded?

Comment: If the files don't really get download, the users won't really be able to see them.  How are you going to stop users making a copy of the files in the temp folder while they're looking at them?  If you want complete control of the device then start off by giving users the device, getting complete control of someone else's device isn't going to work in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can delete user cache/temp folder via web, but you can protect your pdf and doc files with password and disable copy/paste and print function.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your document flash .swf then use google swiify to convert it to html5 !