# File Download using HTML 5 , Javascript and File API

Tags: html, fileapi

Can we integrate the FileAccess API of HTML with normal download of Files using javascript.

We typically download a file by the below way:

```
var fileUrl='../File.doc';    
window.open(fileUrl,'Downloading');
```

Now I believe that the file would be downloaded to tempFolder and the folder designated by us for download.

But is it possible for us to download the file to a sandboxed location as mentioned in [WWC draft on HTML 5 File  API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/).

If this is possible, I believe "need for a way to delete downloaded files" of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551675/is-it-possible-to-protect-our-documents-from-getting-copied-using-html-5-or-gener) would be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new [`download` attribute](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download) you can add to links that tells the browser to download the resource rather than navigating to it. That downloads the file to whatever "Downloads" folder the browser uses by default. You cannot programmatically delete files that are downloaded. That would be a security risk.